# IIS - login by domain name is ok; login by IP address fails

Tags: iis, login, windows-authentication

I configured IIS server to use Windows authentication.
On a client computer, I used IE to open a website of IIS by

1. domain name - this resulted in automatic login.
2. IP address - a dialog box appeared asking for username/password. I entered the correct username/password and still the website refused access.

What is the cause and solution of this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IE treats any IP address as Internet Zone by default. IE also doesn't allow automatic logon in the Internet Zone by default.  You can either change that setting, or you can add the IP address to Intranet Zones in IE.